# Call subclasses with static methods

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, subclass

I sometimes need the behavior of calling subclass methods statically.
In example I have a group of `messengers`. That I need to call once or twice in each implementation, I do not feel like keeping variables of their super interface since then I would need to have one method description for all, or several that all would be obliged to overwrite. And they would not be static.

I want to be able to do something like `Messenger.MessageErrorMessage.send(param)` or `Messenger.MessageDefaultMessage`, etc... Need to bind them to a superclass, but still keep the static behavior when calling subclass methods.

So I've done this below:
The interface has public innerclasses which call the subclass static methods with the only change in name being `MessageErrorMessages` (actual subclass) `MessageErrorMessage` (inner class) only need to change name from plural name to singular name.

```
  Interface Messenger{
     public static final class MessageErrorMessage{
        public static void send(Message message){
          MessageErrorMessages.send(Message);
        }
     }
     public static final class MessageDefaultMessage{
        public static void send(Message message){
           MessageDefaultMessages.send(Message);
        }
     }
  }
```

The actual implementation of **interface Messenger**..

```
 MessageErrorsMessages implements Messenger {
        public static void send(Message message){
        //..Implementation of send
        }
    }
```

The actual implementation of **interface Messenger**..

```
   MessageDefaultMessages  implements Messenger{
        public static void send(Message message){
        //..Implementation of send
        }
    }
```

This way I don't have to keep in mind 20 different types of `Messenger` subclasses and needing to keep their variables.
Is this breaking any design rules?

Edit: 
I want to be able to write

```
Messenger.MessageException.send(message, throwable);
```

and at the same time

```
Messenger.MessageDefaultMessage.send(message);
```

I want the subclasses with their own unique behaviour and method decklarations but still collected under Messenger.

Comment: I think the main design flaw is, that a Message implements a Messenger. You couple information (Message) to functionality (Messenger).

What was the reason, not to use something like Messenger.sendMessage(message)?

Comment: Since I want to keep the interface uncluttered with several innerclasses and long methodbodys, still I want to keep the logic in seperate classes,

Comment: Huhm,.. could you provide some information about the different Message types? What kind of different behaviors of a send(message) do you have? From what I see, the main goal is to transport a message and I can't think of different behaviors on how you transport or serialize a message. You could even use a send(message) instead of send(message, throwable), if you treat the throwable as information...

Comment: Sure, Messenger static methods are called both by receiving classes, and by DAOS,etc, they are used in different packages, In example DAOs use messenger only to dispatch message with results, while  receiving classes would only use it when exceptions are caught or something else that the DAOs cannot control. Each job that dispatched has it own contract to a queue... so I need to keep all codes seperated but gathered when I need to request its services..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish (I'm not sure I understand your question) but it seems you want to basically override static methods in subclasses so you can then call the method on an instance and have it delegate to the subclass method. This is simply not possible. Any static methods will be called on the class you call them on (note that you call static methods on a class, *not* on an instance. Most compilers/IDEs will throw a warning if you try to call a static method on an instance because that can obscure which class you are actually calling it on).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want the ability to use static methods from the `*Messages` classes as well as have a generic `Messenger` class that delegates to the appropriate `*Messages` class. I do not see how you can do this other than the method you proposed.

That said, IMO, you should either use `Messenger` or `*Messages` classes in your application code. Using both leads to confusion down the line.

Comment: No no I should not have access to the Messages, only to Message, I will only be able to call on Messangers innerclasses method which delegates to the Implementation classes. Just to not have to remember each Messages name when using them in the code, is that totally unnecessary and not litter the interface with long innerclasses?